# Dropping specific rows in pandas using the index number

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having some issues to take out the index number of some rows on my script.

I wanna only take the Country names for my table, I already added "dropna()" to take out the empty rows, but I failed to take the index of the rows on the Col1 that starts with 'Total'.

The content on the panda file is like this:

The Country is the Col1, 1975 the Col2 and 1966 the Col3, more (also the index number)

In[1]:

```
 Index Country     1965      1966
 0     NaN          NaN        NaN
 1     Canada       115.9     123.0
 2     Mexico       25.0      26.4
 3     US           1249.6    1320.0
 4     Total...     1390.5    1469.5
 5     NaN          NaN        NaN      
 6     Argentina    26.9       27.8
 7     Brazil       22.5       24.5
 8     Chile        6.2        6.6
 9     Colombia     7.5        8.2
 10    Ecuador      0.8        0.8
 11    Peru         4.8        5.8
 12    Trinidad...  3.0        3.2
 13    Venezuela    16.4       16.6
 14    Central...   4.3        4.4
 15    Other...     15.0       15.7
 16    Other...     2.6        3.0
 17    Total...     110.0      116.6
 18    NaN          NaN        NaN
 19    Austria      15.8       16.6
```

My plan is to take the index row number of these 'Total' rows using pandas and drop these lines, with this part of the data, will the rows 4 and 17. (cause I also wrote the dropna() to take off the empty rows.

Because when I take out the lines, the index number stay the same, but I stucked on the part where I can take the index number using the rows where starts with 'Total' on the Country column.

So I'd like to record this index numbers on a list to use as df.drop(index=numbers), being numbers the list on the index rows of the 'Total' cells

So the output will be:
In[2]: df.drop(index=numbers)

```
 Index Country     1965      1966
 1     Canada       115.9     123.0
 2     Mexico       25.0      26.4
 3     US           1249.6    1320.0    
 6     Argentina    26.9       27.8
 7     Brazil       22.5       24.5
 8     Chile        6.2        6.6
 9     Colombia     7.5        8.2
 10    Ecuador      0.8        0.8
 11    Peru         4.8        5.8
 12    Trinidad...  3.0        3.2
 13    Venezuela    16.4       16.6
 14    Central...   4.3        4.4
 15    Other...     15.0       15.7
 16    Other...     2.6        3.0
 19    Austria      15.8       16.6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use boolean indexing:

```
df = df[df['Country'].ne('Total...')].dropna(how='all')
```

or

```
df = df[~df['Country'].str.startswith('Total')].dropna(how='all')
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Work perfectly, I choose the second cause I also can take only the Total rows for another table. You also answered future question of mine. Thanks again